# Using HLL_COUNT.MERGE as an analytic function

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in which I count my daily active users using HLL-sketches. I have a lot of dimensions and metrics, but the problem only really occurs when I want to do this:

```
SELECT 
    pet_type,
    SUM(number_of_pets_owned) as total_pets,
    SUM(number_of_pets_owned)/HLL_COUNT.MERGE(population) as pets_per_person,
FROM
    pet_database
GROUP BY
    partitiontime,
    pet_type
```

The issue when I do this is that each pets_pet_person is always > 1, since the sketch is grouped by pet_type. What I really want to do is use something like an analytic function `OVER (PARTITION BY partitiontime)`. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    pet_type,
    SUM(number_of_pets_owned) as total_pets,
    SUM(number_of_pets_owned)/HLL_COUNT.MERGE(population) OVER (PARTITION BY partitiontime) as pets_per_person,
FROM
    pet_database
GROUP BY
    partitiontime,
    pet_type
```

... to see how common pets are among the population. But this is invalid syntax, as HLL is not supported by aggregating analytic functions.

Am I tackling this problem wrong, or is there a easy solution I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

What if you did a JOIN with the total instead?

Like in

```
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT wiki, HLL_COUNT.INIT(title) sketch
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
  WHERE DATE(datehour) = "2019-01-27"
  AND wiki LIKE 'a%'
  GROUP BY wiki
)

SELECT wiki, HLL_COUNT.MERGE(sketch) count,
  FORMAT('%.2f%%', 100* HLL_COUNT.MERGE(sketch)
    / (SELECT HLL_COUNT.MERGE(sketch) FROM sample_table)
  ) percent
FROM sample_table 
GROUP BY wiki
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

[image]